# Windows 10 ridiculously slow after 20H2 update

Tags: windows-10

After 20H2 update, I can't seem to get my apps fuction properly. Every app I try to launce (I.E Steam) takes a 4 minutes or five to load.
I have a room of 32 gb ram and my windows is installed on 1tb m.2 of ssd.
What can I do in order to fix this?

Comment: You will need to give us more details.  You will need to explain in explicit details, using specific language, to describe in what way your computer is slow.  It sounds like your CPU is running at a lower frequency.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  **I suggest you revert back to the previous feature update for the time being**

Comment: You might try a Repair Install from the Media Creation Link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 ) to see if that fixes the issue. I have 20H2 running on 2 machines here and 21H2 running on 1 machine with no performance issues.

Comment: @John: If he does that he won't be able to revert to his previous version.

Comment: 20H2 works well so I know a Repair will keep the current version but my thought is to repair it.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the latest release of Windows: https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-slow-cpu-frequency/

Comment: @John - While 20H2 is indeed fine, there is a bug, that is making CPU frequency report as 0.79 GHz for some users.  It's not clear based on the [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/10/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-19042-608-20h2/) post by Microsoft, if the CPU frequency is actually that speed, or if something else is going on.  The fact "everything takes 4 or 5 minutes to load", tells me, that the actual frequency is that slow.

Comment: I know that. But Microsoft has a great many combinations to test for, and I think the top quality machines tend to be less affected by this bug. None of mine for sure.

Comment: Look, I do have 10900k installed and I tested the frequency, I am running on 3.21 ghz average. I found out everything is OK as long as I don't use windows settings. Then things tend to get worse.

Comment: What "Windows settings" do you need to not use?

Comment: Just when I press settings, it's teerible. Anyhow noted, when on build 1909 when system is idle frequency averaged at 70% and on 20H2 it is 100% all the time.

Comment: I have figured my problem, ram is incompatible with the mobo, bought compatible set. I feel too stupid..