# How do I prevent Windows 10 version 20H2 from redownloading and installing after deleting the update directory?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I accidentally clicked an icon in my tray, that is usually for just restarting once an update installed, however this time it consented to 20H2 installing (merely with a single click - I thought it would open the Windows Update Settings screen to ask me to schedule a reboot time, rather than agree to this) because 1909, which I am on, will not be supported. I tried deleting the update directory (C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download) and it just redownloaded 20H2. I do not want this version as it is still experimental and I have seen on Youtube videos that it is responsible for high CPU usage for some people not to mention [1] (if I could update to 2004 which is known to be more stable, I would do that but it is not available). I know it's possible to revert the update within 10 days, but I'd like to avoid the risk and time involved with that as well as the possibility that it will just restart the cycle of downloading and installing 20H2 once I do that.

[1] [Windows 10 ridiculously slow after 20H2 update](https://superuser.com/questions/1598702/windows-10-ridiculously-slow-after-20h2-update)

[2]https://www.google.com/search?q=20h2+problems

[3] https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-october-2020-update-biggest-problems-and-complaints

Comment: It is recommended you frequently backup your system e.g. using a imaging backup software. Then if you are afraid of upgrades you can just test them if you are really affected and if it really affects you go back by restoring the last backup before installing the upgrade. As the chance is low that would sill be affected it saves a lot of time and for important systems a recent backup is important anyway.

Comment: 20H2 has been out 6 months. How many of those complaints are from within the last month? Your first link ended up being incompatible RAM, not the OS. The rest I didn't read, it's ancient history by now.

Comment: Robert: Fully backing up the OS is a tedious process, may involve more softare/hardware and even more cumbersome with an impending update. The lay user, or even a user on a critical system shouldn't have to worry about that, nor should they be tricked into updating by clicking a tray icon.
Tetsujin: I am still not comfortable having an update forced upon my system even if I am taking your word that it's safe. It hasn't been rolled out to enough systems to completely insure safety of a critical PC. We're paying for the OS, we shouldn't have to subject a system to its experimental development.

Comment: Robert/Tetsujin: thanks for categorizing as comments, however neither give any meaningful way to prevent an update which is the purpose of this question (rather than asking 'why shouldn't I update'.

Comment: Build 1909 is almost EoL. 20H2 is not 'experimental', it's de-facto. 21H1 will be out soon & whilst I would always advocate hanging on a month or so until bugs get shaken out, constantly trying to run two years behind releases really isn't going to help you in the slightest. If you don't update to 20H2 shortly, you will then be forced onto 21H1, which I'm sure you'd be even less happy with.